# Защита от выполнение js кода

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть страница на сайте, на неё происходит вставка куска html кода из внешнего источника.
Например, есть товар, а описание товара предоставляет поставщик в виде html описания.

Как можно запретить выполнение любого js и т.п. кода из этого описания?

т.е.

```
<span>Описание товара</span>
Вставленное описание поставщика
```

При этом, описание содержит нужную html разметку, а нужно запретить именно возможность выполнения скриптов и обработчиков событий.

Можно удалить простым образом всю разметку, типа, strip_tags, но разметка нужна.

Скорее всего, есть какое-либо простое готовое решение, но не нашёл...
В голову приходит с помощью регулярок убрать  все onclick= onchange  и т.п..
Может быть есть готовые решения или что-либо типа

```
<no_execute_sript>
Вставленное описание поставщика
</no_execute_sript>
```

Comment: htmlentities для пыхи например  суть - все символы преобразовать в html сущности типа &lg;  и пр

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, тогда и html разметка преобразуется, <span> и тд. нужно именно выполнение кода запретить или убрать.

Comment: Взять какой-нибудь html-парсер, пройтись по всему дереву элементов и удалить те теги и атрибуты, которые не входят в список разрешённых (по идее должны существовать готовые реализации для этого, но мне лень их искать)

Comment: И да, значения разрешённых атрибутов тоже нужно проверять, так как html позволяет написать скрипт внутри ссылок например: `<a href="javascript:alert('я супер хацкер');">Ссылка</a>`

Comment: andreymal, мой вопрос как раз и заключался в поиске простого готового решения данного вопроса.
руками все запрещать сложно, как мне кажется. что-то же должно быть готовое, 100% я не первый этим озадачился.

Comment: "Запрещающий" подход опасен, потому что в будущем разработчики html могут захотеть изобрести какой-нибудь новый тег/атрибут для скриптов, а вы забудете его запретить. Поэтому нужно делать наоборот - разрешать строго определённый набор тегов/атрибутов и запрещать всё неизвестное.

Answer (score 2):

Решение одно и классическое:

> **Никогда** не вставляйте данные на страницу из внешних источников без предварительной обработки.

В вашем случае это означает, что вам нужно получить данные со внешней страницы, распарсить их и записать уже в своей собственной разметке себе на страницу

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133370/discussion-on-answer-by-anton-shchyrov----js-).